Rails Deployment failing due to jsbundling-rails not recognizing yarn: Command install failed, ensure yarn is installed
I am trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails app on an ubuntu VM. I have installed yarn both for the app's user and for root. yarn -v returns a version successfully. However, when trying to deploy using Capistrano, the deployment fails with the following log:
 DEBUG [5be47f05] Command: cd /apps/safehub-central/project/releases/20241129043204 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="" RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
 DEBUG [5be47f05]   rake aborted!
 DEBUG [5be47f05]   jsbundling-rails: Command install failed, ensure yarn is installed
 DEBUG [5be47f05]   /apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jsbundling-rails-1.1.2/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/cli.rb:492:in `exec'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/exe/bundle:45:in `block in <top (required)>'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
/apps/safehub-central/project/shared/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.8/exe/bundle:33:in `<top (required)>'
/apps/safehub-central/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/apps/safehub-central/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
 DEBUG [5be47f05]   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build => javascript:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I used nvm to install node and yarn. The following is my %PATH
/apps/safehub-central/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin:/apps/safehub-central/.rbenv/shims:/apps/safehub-central/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin


Please check the following to debug this issue:

Ensure Yarn is Installed Globally:
yarn global bin

If Yarn was not installed globally you can use this command:
npm install -g yarn

Check Capistrano's PATH
production.rb file:
set :default_environment, {
'PATH' => "/apps/safehub-central/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin:$PATH"
}
OR
SSHKit.config.command_map[:yarn] = "/apps/safehub-central/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin/yarn"

Debug PATH During Deployment
namespace :debug do
desc "Echo $PATH"
task :echo_path do
on roles(:app) do
execute "echo $PATH"
end
end
end



I checked yarn is indeed installed globally.
3) I added this to deploy/production.rb and deployed but same error again.
4) Running that task returns
      01 echo $PATH
      01 /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games


it's good to double check by running yarn --version
